# What Relationship will this scenario be?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have these two models in my MVC app: **Shareholder** and **ShareTransfer**.

The logic I have is that 1 or more shareholders can transfer shares to another 1 or more shareholder. How do I handle this in a relationship especially in Entity Framework?

Your usual quick response is much expected. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my aspect of view each transfer from one shareholder to another should be unique. Hence:

[image]

On the other hand if you are looking for one single transfer from one or more to one or more:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot **@TSungur** for your answer. It has really solidify my decision because I had the same design as that you have presented but was wondering if I was right. It has greatly put a sigh of relieve on me. Now what type of relationship is this and how do I represent it in EF?

Comment: Whic one are we talking about? Option 1 or 2?

Comment: well since all transfers are unique for every transfer you will have one sourceshareholder and one targetshareholder. Which will make it a one to one relation. public class Transfer{public int TransferId {get;set;} public virtual ShareHolder SourceShareHolder {get;set;} public virtual ShareHolder TargetShareHolder {get;set;}} something like this

Comment: Great to have you answer my doubts. Thanks a lot will try and if any doubt again won't hesitate to get back to you. tnx